# if $X$ and $Y$ are Normal random variables with same parameters. is $(aX+bX)=(aX+bY)$?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

if $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and both are $\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, ie share the same average and variance. Then we defined a new random variable as the linear combination of them as: $Z=(aX+bY)$ is that the same as saying $Z=(aX+bX)$? Is $Z=(aX+bX)$ the same as saying $Z=((a+b)X)$?

Comment: Assume that $\mu=0$, $\sigma^2=1$, and $a=b=1$, then $X$ and $Y=-X$ are both $N(0,1)$. Do you think that $X+Y$ and $X+Y$ are "the same", in the sense that they follow the same distribution?

Comment: *typo: "Do you think that X+Y and X+X are "the same", in the sense..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm *absolutely sure* the answer is **no,** unless $X$ and $Y$ are exactly the same random variable $(X \equiv Y).$ But @MarcusLuebke raises good points (+1), especially about independence.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables. Consider $\mu =2,\, \sigma=1$ and
$a =3,\,b=2.$ Let $W_1 = 3X + 2Y,\, W_2 = 3Y + 2X,$ and $W_3 = 3X + 2X = 5X.$

Then you can use standard formulas to show that $E(W_1) = E(W_2) = E(W_3) = 10.$
But $Var(W_1) = Var(W_2) = (a^2 + b^2)\sigma^2 = 13,$ while $Var(W_3) =25.$ All of three of the $W_i$ are normal.

Samples simulated to these specifications have the following histograms.
As noted above, the bottom plot (for $W_3$) shows greater variability: the vertical red lines are at $\mu_w \pm \sigma_w$ in each case.

[image]

Comment: Thank your for Accepting my Answer. I'm glad if it helped you understnd the main issue. From the way you stated the question, I guessed this would be an answer at the right level. // However, the approach in @MichaelHardy's Answer is more comprehensive (+1). If you understand joint and marginal distributions, it is certainly worth your while to  read it carefully.

Answer (score 1):

You have not said how $X$ and $Y$ are **jointly** distributed, but only how they are marginally distributed.

If they are both marginally distributed as $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then:

- At one extreme you have $X=Y,$ in which case $X+Y= 2X \sim N(2\mu,4\sigma^2).$
- At an opposite extremem you have $Y = 2\mu-X,$ in which case $X+Y\sim N(2\mu,0),$ i.e. the sum is constant.
- Somewhere in between, $X$ and $Y$ are independent. In that case $X+Y\sim N(2\mu, 2\sigma^2).$
- And there are cases where there is a nonzero correlation between $X$ and $Y$ but it's not $+1$ or $-1.$
- There are also cases in which $X$ and $Y$ are not jointly normally distributed (but still have that same marginal distribution). One of those is where $Y = \pm X$ with plus and minus having equal probabilities and being chosen independently of $X$. In that case $X+Y$ is not normally distributed, since $\Pr(X+Y=0) = 1/2.$

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no. An easy way to think about this is physically. AX+BX corresponds to the same event happening twice, whereas AX+BY corresponds to two separate, INDEPENDENT events occuring. With AX+BX, you pull the same point out of the distribution (causing an amplification), whereas with AX+BY, you pull different points (probably causing an increase in variance).

However, I'm not an expert, and there might be some weird mathematical symmetry I don't know about, but I would put it at 94.9% confidence that it is different.